# Alterar vírgula por ponto

Tags: javascript

Quero que quando um usuário digite `,` (vírgula), esta seja substituída por `.` (ponto). Mas quando insiro o script abaixo, o mesmo não apresenta nenhum resultado.

Alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

```js
function substituiPonto(){
    valor = document.calcform.visor.value;
    while(valor.indexOf(".") >= 0) {
        novoValor = valor.replace(",",".");
    }
    valor = novoValor;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form name="calcform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="visor" id="visor" value="" onKeyPress="substituiPonto()"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Lembre-se de marcar uma resposta como certa caso alguma tenha resolvido seu problema amigo, assim outras pessoas que pesquisarem tambem serão ajudadas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow @Moises ;)
Na sua função você está apenas pegando o valor do input `document.calcform.visor.value`, trantando ele `novoValor = valor.replace(",",".")` e atribuindo ele a variavel `valor = novoValor`, mas em momento nenhum está setando o valor do input com essa variavel.

Coloque isso no final de sua função e ja deve funcionar:

```
function substituiPonto(){
    ... Faz o tratamento da string aqui
    document.calcform.visor.value = valor; // coloca o valor no input novamente
}
```

Mas há um jeito mais simples de fazer o que você precisa:

```js
function substituir(el) {
    el.value = el.value.replace(",", ".");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="substituir(this);" />
```

Answer (score 5):

O seu código não funciona já que você está usando o `replace` para trocar os pontos (`.`) por "nada" (`''`).

Além disso, creio que o loop `while` não seja tão necessário nessa situação.

---

Você pode, então, fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
document.querySelector('#field').addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const el = event.target
  if (el.value.includes(',')) {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/,/g, '.')
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field" />
```

Basicamente, criamos um *listener* ao evento `keyup` que irá verificar se o valor do campo tem uma vírgula. Se tiver, a vírgula será substituída pelo ponto.

Note que você também pode usar o método `indexOf` ao invés do `includes` se desejar.

#### Referência:

- [`keyup` (evento)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/keyup);
- [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes);
- [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf);
- [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 3):

Você tá trocando o "." por um valor vazio, o replace tem que ser assim

```
replace(",", ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o seguinte código:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="calcform" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="visor" id="visor" value="" onKeyPress="substituiPonto()"/>
        </form>

    <script>
    function substituiPonto(){
    valor = document.calcform.visor.value;

    document.getElementById("visor").value = valor.replace(",", ".");
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Utilizando a função `replace(",", ".")` para fazer a sua substituição.